# Using Routing with PHP Good or Bad idea?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I conditionally show different pages to users depending on the URL through PHP & Mysql. It presently is simple PHP page which uses `$_GET['page']`. I am also using `htaccess URL rewrite` to make pages more SEO, Mysql for data and `Smarty` as my template engine.

I am thinking of adding more features and grow it to a full fledged Forum/Blog/Groups with lot of URL parameters. Thought to switch to MVC frameworks but they are much much more than what I need and far more technical. However they told me about Router and I realized that my simple PHP page is exactly working like that. I want to keep this router simple so am using switch statement to get pages for preselected `page` and `default` to home page. While I decided not to unnecessarily complicate matter by using any MVC but I am still confused and request your views about :

**1. Is this approach correct ?**  I read

> A web application by its very nature is a series of small discrete
>   requests. If you send all of your requests through a single controller
>   on a single machine you have just defeated this very important
>   architecture.

at http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html which increased my confusion !

**2. Is this way secure ?**  I saw most PHP Routers use some kind of regex for checking parameters for sanitizing. I am simply doing it with `PHP switch` !

**3. Is it scalable ?** I do not have much traffic max 3000 per day. Will this router approach slow down my website with more traffic.

**4. Is including pages better than redirecting ?** Since I was `redirecting` users after this router, conditionally, I am thinking to `include` PHP pages it in PHP router itself. Which will be a better approach ?

Sorry if it seems stupid to some but I wasted 2 days to understand how MVC will help me and found that I am better off without MVC framework just worried, whether I am doing things right !

Comment: 1. Don't take advice from Rasmus Lerdorf, 2. Most probably, providing the router doesn't do much more than routem, 3. Depends on the router. If it's a heavy router with lots of features it might not scale, but other parts of your app will be the bottleneck and 4. Including is _always_ better than redirecting

Comment: Why not try Codeigniter, the best MVC (for me) out there. It makes routing a piece of cake.

Comment: @Houssni, Rasmus Lerdorf is the creator of PHP.

Comment: You don't need to redirect or include files. Just make an instance of the right controller and execute one of his methods (mostly called "actions" )

Comment: @Chris Why is taking advice of him a bad idea? lol

Comment: @jahajee.com I think you could better include the page instead of redirect the users.

Comment: @Bojangles Ah right! Thanks, I always think like; if they create it then they are the only one who does everything right and perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have actually had the same experience as you did. I used a pretty similar approach as you. I had all of my activity go to my router PHP file and from there I would parse the URL and call whatever controller needed to be called. Also, to call my page I would simply do an `include`, which would not be a performance hit. This system seemed to work well for routing.

All that said, I would encourage you to really check out a framework if you want to scale a website. I am not saying you won't be able to scale with what you got but the road will be a lot longer. That is simply because you are going to have to do or repeat the same thing the framework is doing. I recommend a lightweight framework such as the Yii Framework. Before you commit to it I would encourage you to play around with it a bit and see if it all makes sense. If it does, it's well worth the time and effort to upgrade to it. I did the same thing for my site and I am able to add new features very fast.

1. Yes, your approach would be correct.
2. It's secure up to a point. You will need to validate your parameters yourself and perform SQL injection escaping when running your queries. Again, this is something built into frameworks, so why do it yourself? Although it's easy to do.
3. Yes, it's scalable; the frameworks are running the same type of pattern. As long as you have the hardware to support it, it will be fine.
4. Yes, including is better than redirecting as it won't have to make another request to your server, instead running it all on the same request.

As for your last point: two days probably isn't enough to learn the whole MVC architecture. I went though the same process 3 years ago for work. It was very painful, but after a couple of weeks I noticed I was able to be more organized with my code and didn't have SQL queries sitting around all over the place. I tried several frameworks: Cake, Zend, Symphony and Yii. I settled on Yii because it seems the best to me.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation and pointing towards simple framework. Since router switches the `pages` between predefined set of variables only (no DB interaction at router) sql injection will load just default page. On later redirected pages I secure data for all checks. Since I hand coded my website without any framework I am presently knowing in-out of this website, so will avoid MVC framework for now however noted `codeigniter` and `yii` for future trying out.

Comment: Yeah I was in the same situation as you. I had a ton of code writing and actually had a user base on my site. I decided to go the framework route as the benefits out weight the cons for me. For example with the Yii framework you can pull in extensions and not have to write everything yourself. Again your choice.